# Implementing custom keras metric with outside parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to implement a custom metric to evaluate my model on a per-epoch basis using values not included in my training set to evaluate predictions.

The idea of my metric:

```
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred, other_values):
   """
   y_true is training data, binary value
   y_pred is predicted values 
   other_values is an inputted tensor, includes values in (0, 2) """

   Use K backend to return the proper value.
   ...
```

There may be other ways to do the same computation, effectively solving the same problem. One of which would be to checkpoint the model at every epoch and run this analysis after training is completed. However, I would prefer not to since I am training on TPU and copying weights to CPU requires compiling at each epoch and would 100x training time.

Does someone have a clever way of implementing this technique? Either in a metric or some other method?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this would be to use a wrapping function:

I.e.

```
def custom_metric(my_variable):
   # 1. conversion of my_variable to tensor
   def metric_name(y_pred, y_true):
      # 2. return tensorflow backend metric, utilizing custom tensor
   return metric_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the Keras [Metric](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#as-subclasses-of-metric-stateful) base class, provide `other_values` in `__init__`, and provide `y_true` and `y_pred` in the `update_state` method:

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric

class CustomMetric(Metric):
    def __init__(self, other_values):
        self.other_values = other_values
        ''' perform any calculations that don't rely on a specific y_true or y_pred
        '''

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred):
        ''' calculate loss using previously stored self.other_values, etc.
        '''
```

Another option would be to create a custom Layer and use the [add_metric API](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#the-addmetric-api).  That would be especially useful if your `other_values` relate back to the architecture of the layer, or if you need to perform the metric calculations on an intermediary step.